# Create an array from unnested row in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested

Hello I have a set of data as follow:

[image: base dataset]

I have ids going from 1 to 6.
There must be an entry with the same timestamp for rows with id from 2 to 6.

I created this request:

```
SELECT  t.timestamp, t.id, v.id FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` as t CROSS JOIN `myproject.mydataset.mytable` as v WHERE v.id <> t.id AND v.timestamp = t.timestamp AND t.id =2 ORDER BY t.timestamp
```

and it gives me this output:

[image: query resuly]

We can see that I get a row attaching id from 3 to 6 to id 2 when the timestamp is the same. What I'd like to achieve is return only 1 line by timestamp and in the column 'id_1' have an array with [3,4,5,6].

I saw there's a NEST() function but I can't manage to use it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are describing `ARRAY_AGG()`:

```
SELECT t.timestamp, t.id, ARRAY_AGG(v.id)
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable` t JOIN 
     `myproject.mydataset.mytable` v
     ON v.timestamp = t.timestamp
WHERE v.id <> t.id AND t.id = 2
GROUP BY t.timestamp, t.id
ORDER BY t.timestamp
```